# espresso test: how to control the content of an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, mocking, mockito, android-espresso

I have the following code in my activity class:

```
@Override
public boolean onClick(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(getExternalFilesDir(null)).getAbsolutePath();
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder");

    if (intent.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0) != null)
    {
        // case 1: another app exists
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        // case 2: no app, so open dialog
        DialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
    }
    return true;
}
```

In my Espresso test, how can I test both cases on the same device (without uninstalling/reinstalling the other app)?
I had a look at Espresso intents and Mockito but haven't find a way to do that.

Comment: What does `// case 1: another app exists` means? And what is another app, and what is the difference between no app and having an app?

Comment: Case 1: a "file explorer" app has been found on the device, so we will open it.  
Case 2: no file explorer has been found on the device, so we display a dialog box to ask the user to install a file explorer

Answer (score 0):

Since you have this line of code here:
intent.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0)

You can try to programmatically set this to not be null before running your tests.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do, but I don't  know how to do it.  From my test code, how to mock this call and return null?